# How & where to learn Flutter & Dart?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, user-interface

I am a Product Designer looking to start app development for personal projects.
I am new to flutter, I have picked flutter for app development, and I am new to just started a few weeks ago, I wanted to ask if someone could guide me on what are the things that I need to learn to make apps that are fast, robust and useful.
please do mention resources from where I can learn flutter too.

Would greatly appreciate your help.

Comment: I think This question will get closed under  [Recommendation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/332775/10157127)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever path you take, start with the Google-provided well-written up-to-date documentation, namely:

on dart.dev:

- read the entire tour
- skim the library tour
- do the codelabs

on flutter.dev:

- read the overview material
- install flutter as directed there (and nowhere else)
- do the codelabs
- skim the cookbook

and never read a blog post or watch a video older than six months old without seeking the advice of an expert.